# Google Places blocks Server Backend for Mobile App

Tags: django, google-places-api

I'm developing a mobile application that presents users with information about nearby places (combining my own information with Google Places data), but Google Places seems to have blocked my application.

Is what I'm doing out of the TOS, and if not, is there a way to whitelist my server application?

The current flow is

1. User on mobile app requests nearby places on their device
2. GPS coordinates are sent to Server (Django backend)
3. Server builds the Google Places request with GPS Coordinates, makes the request and then combines the returned Google Places JSON with my own data
4. Server returns the combined data to the User

Everything worked perfectly until out of nowhere, it seems that Google Places has blocked my application. I'm well within the request limit and have properly attributed Google within my mobile app. Requests with my API Key work as long as they don't come from my server application.

I've read the Terms of Service and don't believe I've done anything out of scope. Is there a way to whitelist my server/IP? Or a better approach to this problem?

Comment: Hi mike. What HTTP response code and body are you getting back from the Google Places API when you make a request from your server?

Comment: I'm getting a 403 response code, although for sure I'm not exceeding the usage limits as I'm only making 100-200 requests per day. I think it has something to do with the fact the calls are being made by my server application, because the exact same request made in CURL or browser return the expected results.

Comment: It looks like this might have been a temporary configuration issue; can you try again and let me know if it is now resolved?

Comment: That's great, it works just as expected now.